# Using pointers to navigate an array, instead of using an int

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

How would I use pointers in my program to keep track of the current position of array, instead of using "counter"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void){

int counter = 0, c;
char *charPtr, characterArray[MAX] = { 0 };

printf("Enter a message: ");

for (c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar()){
    charPtr = &characterArray[0];
    characterArray[*charPtr++] = c;
}

counter = strlen(characterArray) - 1;
printf("The reverse order is: ");

while (counter >= 0){
    printf("%c", characterArray[counter]);
    --counter;
}
printf("\n\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Not clear what you actually want. You can have a pointer to your array and derefernce it to store the value

Comment: I posted up what I have tried, I just didn't upload it at first because it was so bad. It only takes the first letter entered then skips the rest. Not sure why it is doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void){

        int  c;
        char characterArray[MAX] = { 0 };
        char *ptr = NULL;
        ptr = characterArray;

        printf("Enter a message: ");

        for (c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar()){
                *ptr = c;
                ptr++;
        }
                *ptr = '\0';
        printf("The reverse order is: ");

        while ( ptr != characterArray ){
                printf("%c", *ptr);
                --ptr;
        }
        printf ( "%c",*ptr);
        printf("\n\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain to me your code :) ?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly like this:

```
char *endptr = characterArray + strlen(characterArray) - 1;

printf("The reverse order is: ");

while (endptr >= characterArray){
    printf("%c", *endptr--);
}
```

Code is untested.

Comment: After this, `endptr` will point to `characterArray[-1]`, which is UB.

Comment: @glglgl : `endptr` will just **point** to `characterArray[-1]`, which is not undefined behaviour as long as you don't dereference it. Otherwise `char *x = NULL` would be undefined behaviour as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
// This program takes the user input then reverses it. 
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void)
{
    char characterArray[MAX] = { 0 };
    char *p = characterArray;
    char c;

    printf("Enter a message: ");

    for ( c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar() )
    {
        *p++ = c;
    }

    printf("The reverse order is: ");

    while ( p != characterArray )
    {
        printf( "%c",  *--p );
    }

    printf( "\n\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
Hello, World
```

then output will be

```
dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses, I will take my time studying this.